# ccache with same code base and multiple toolchains

Tags: gcc, icc, ccache

Our system supports being built with three different toolchains (gcc, icc, diab). I am not sure if using ccache is safe in this case. My concern is the following: if I build with gcc, and then rebuild with diab, will I get a ccache hit in the case the files and their dependencies are the same ?

I *do not* want a hit in this case, since I want the files to be recompiled with diab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will not get a ccache hit between different compilers. The compiler is hashed. Additionally, you can change the environment variable CCACHE_COMPILERCHECK to check the compiler in a different way.
As found in the [ccache manual](http://ccache.samba.org/manual.html#_common_hashed_information):

```
For both modes, the following information is included in the hash:

    the extension used by the compiler for a file with preprocessor output (normally .i for C code and .ii for C++ code)

    the compiler’s size and modification time (or other compiler-specific information specified by CCACHE_COMPILERCHECK)

    the name of the compiler

    the current directory (if CCACHE_HASHDIR is set)

    contents of files specified by CCACHE_EXTRAFILES (if any)
```